# markdown in LaTeX causes compiling issue

Tags: luatex, markdown, vscode, latex-workshop

A generated lua file for embedding markdown cannot be found during build process.

Hello I want to integrate a markdown file in my latex file. Firstly, I tried to run an example for it. However, the build fails because of an error, that says that a lua file cannot be found, which is already in directory.

#### MWE:

`steps.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hashEnumerators,smartEllipses]{markdown}

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
An h1 header
============

Paragraphs are separated by a blank line. 

2nd paragraph. *Italic*, **bold**, and `monospace`. Itemized lists
look like:

* this one
* that one
* the other one

> Block quotes are
> written like so.
>
> They can span multiple paragraphs,
> if you like.

An h2 header
------------

Here's a numbered list (use `hashEnumerators` option if you want to use hashes):

#. first item
#. second item
#. third item
\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

#### Error:

The corresponding line in `steps.log`

```
c:/path/to/directory/steps.tex:42: I can't find file `"|texlua ./steps.markdown.lua"'.
```

#### Environment:

- texlive 2022
- VSCode with LaTeX Workshop plugin and I have listed build arguments below

```
{
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32/latexmk.exe",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-pdf",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "lualatexmk",
        "command": "C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32/latexmk.exe",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-lualatex",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-output-directory=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
```

Comment: your absolute pathes (`C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32/latexmk.exe`) sounds as if you are not in the current directory when you start the compilation.

Comment: Yes, they just indicate the executables. Since, this path is in the system path. I can actually remove and keep it like `latexmk.exe`. However, it does not help. Except `markdown` all the packages I used work without problem.

Comment: try without the outdir settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the recipe. When markdown is used in LaTeX, one should choose `lualatexmk` recipe (whose parameters are shown in the question) instead of the default recipe.

[image]

Comment: Note that your solution and the tags used for your question does not really match the title of your question. To make this more useful to others it might be an idea to add extra tags and rephrase the title.

Comment: Hopefully it is now more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If compiling from the command line with `latexmk`, rather than from LaTeX-Workshop (in which case see [Reactionic's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656668/301820)), use the `-pdflua` or `-dvilua`, as appropriate, rather than the `pdflatex` counterparts of `-pdf` or `-dvi`.

I.e., use

```
latexmk -pdfdvi (...other flags...) input_file.tex
```

and **not**

```
latexmk -pdf (...other flags...) input_file.tex
```